# Angular: testing login function

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I'm moving my first steps in Angular testing. In particular, I am trying to test this function in `LoginComponent`

```
login() {
  this.restApi.login(this.loginForm.value).subscribe((resp) => {
    this.user.username = (resp as any).user;
    this.user.token = (resp as any).tkn;
    this.router.navigate(['/main']);
  });
}
```

`restApi` is an instance of `RestApiService`, a service that makes http calls. To test this function, I wrote this test:

```
describe('LoginComponent', () => {
  let component: LoginComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<LoginComponent>;
  let user = new UserService();
  let httpMock: HttpTestingController;
  let httpClient: HttpClient;
  let testRouter = {
    navigate: jasmine.createSpy('navigate'),
  };

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [ReactiveFormsModule, FormsModule, HttpClientTestingModule],
      declarations: [LoginComponent],
      providers: [
        { provide: Router, useValue: testRouter },
        { provide: UserService, useValue: user },
        RestApiService,
      ],
    }).compileComponents();
    httpClient = TestBed.inject(HttpClient);
    httpMock = TestBed.inject(HttpTestingController);
  }));

  function updateForm() {
    component.loginForm.controls['username'].setValue('bob');
    component.loginForm.controls['password'].setValue('bobspassword');
  }

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(LoginComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    component.ngOnInit();
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should login', () => {
    const loginRes = {
      res: 1,
      spec: 'ok',
      tkn: 'aToken',
      user: 'bob',
    };
    const loginReq = {
      username: 'bob',
      password: 'bobspassword',
    };
    updateForm();
    component.login();
    expect(component.user.token).toBeDefined();
    expect(testRouter.navigate).toHaveBeenCalledWith(['/main']);

    const req = httpMock.expectOne(
      'http://myServerAddress:8080/restEndpoint/login'
    );
    expect(req.request.method).toBe('POST');
    expect(req.request.body).toEqual(loginReq);
    req.flush(loginRes);
  });
});
```

The test fails because `component.user.token` is undefined and it doesn't navigate to `/main`

Can you help me?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be handled using `Mock` rather than making actual http call by calling the service.

```
export class MockRestApiService{
   login(){
     return of({
        user: 'someName',
        tkn: 'someToken'
     })
   }
}
```

Now import this Mock class in `spec` as below:

```
  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [ReactiveFormsModule, FormsModule, HttpClientTestingModule],
      declarations: [LoginComponent],
      providers: [
        { provide: Router, useValue: testRouter },
        { provide: UserService, useValue: user },
        {provide: RestApiService, useClass: MockRestApiService},
      ],
    }).compileComponents();
    httpClient = TestBed.inject(HttpClient);
    httpMock = TestBed.inject(HttpTestingController);
  }));
```

This will return `someToken` as the value for the called function `login()`

Try to take a look at [this article where I have explained a component code with proper mocking.](https://medium.com/@shashankvivek.7/testing-a-component-with-stub-services-and-spies-in-jasmine-1428d4242a49). since you are new to testing, [I would recommend this article to start with](https://medium.com/@shashankvivek.7/say-hi-to-jasmine-karma-in-angular-intro-d728d669a1c7)